# SQL Syntax error using EXISTS

Tags: sql, syntax-error

For some reason I get a syntax error when I try to run this SQL.

```
SELECT C.CUSTNUM
FROM CUSTOMERS AS C
WHERE C.CUSTNUM EXISTS (
    SELECT P.CNUM
    FROM PURCHASES AS P
    WHERE P.PNUM EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM PRODUCTS AS PR
        WHERE PR.MSRP = 9.99 ))
```

I made sure to close off my parenthesis, but I still get a syntax error in the query expression. There's probably something simple that I'm missing in my code. Any ideas? Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT C.CUSTNUM
FROM CUSTOMERS AS C
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT P.CNUM
    FROM PURCHASES AS P
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM PRODUCTS AS PR
        WHERE PR.MSRP = 9.99 ))
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `EXISTS` specify the constraint within the sub query itself. If the sub query returns at least one row for a given condition `C.CUSTNUM = P.CNUM` the condition is considered to be met.

I guess this could be rewritten with a `JOIN` to `PRODUCTS` table.

```
SELECT C.CUSTNUM
FROM CUSTOMERS AS C
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM PURCHASES AS P
    JOIN PRODUCTS AS PR ON
      ON P.PNUM = PR.PNUM -- not sure what column to join on in PRODUCTS
    WHERE
      C.CUSTNUM = P.CNUM -- added the correlation, I believe this is what you mean
      PR.MSRP = 9.99
    )
```

If that's not the case, just stick to your modified query:

```
SELECT C.CUSTNUM
FROM CUSTOMERS AS C
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM PURCHASES AS P
    WHERE 
      EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM PRODUCTS AS PR
        WHERE PR.MSRP = 9.99 
        )
      AND C.CUSTNUM = P.CNUM
```

but beware that the outer subquery would return all rows from `PURCHASES` if there is at least one row in `PRODUCTS` table that has `MSRP = 9.99` regardless of matching of any column (you do not specify any condition of correlation between them).

Answer (score 0):

An example of using EXISTS:

```
create table tab1(id1 number);
create table tab2(id2 number);
insert into tab1 values (1);
insert into tab1 values (2);
insert into tab2 values (2);
select *
from tab1
where exists ( select 1
               from tab2
               where tab2.id2 = tab1.id1
             )
```

result: 2

Notice that the subquery is correlated to the outer one based on some field, which seems to be what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use IN instead of EXISTS

```
SELECT C.CUSTNUM
FROM CUSTOMERS AS C
WHERE C.CUSTNUM IN (
    SELECT P.CNUM
    FROM PURCHASES AS P
    WHERE P.PNUM IN (
        SELECT PR.PNUM /* I'm unsure of the proper column here*/
        FROM PRODUCTS AS PR
        WHERE PR.MSRP = 9.99 ))
```